# Do you know a book or an article about Thompson Group V at level undergraduate or master?

Tags: group-theory

I am studying math at fourth year. this year i must write a paper for finish school. but i cannot find anything about Thompson Group V which talks about V. The papers i found talk about the connection of V to another areas and this is difficult for me because for read these papers i must learn so much terminologies. sometimes i must read and understand a book to understand a phrase in that papers.

Comment: I suppose you have seen the references [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_groups). It is also about the group $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to know that V is also one of the Higman groups $G_{n,r}$, so it might also be useful to find a paper on the Higman groups.  Higman's 1974 paper appears to be available from the Australian National University https://copiesdirect.nla.gov.au/items/import?source=cat&sourcevalue=315228 .